# MVC partial load in document.ready not getting fired

Tags: jquery

I have

```
        <div id="reports">
            <img src="~/Content/img/wait.gif" />Loading reports...
        </div>

...
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('test');
            $("#reports").load('/report');

            $("#reportType").change(checkReportSelection);
            checkReportSelection.apply($("#reportType"));
        });
    </script>
}
```

On my machine, #reports is loaded with data from report controller as soon as this page is loaded. I tried on a different machine, targeting this machine and it worked fine. The host machine is windows 10.

When I deployed it to another machine that is server 2012 r2, "loading reports..." stays and report controller is not invoked (checked using debugger).
I tried using chrome and IE and doesn't work.

I do get alert so I know document.ready is fired.

What could be the issue?
Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a path problem. Inspect the actual ajax request in browser dev tools network for clues

Answer (score 0):

turns out to be issue with path. Thanks Charlietfl.
Using Url.Content(...) worked